# Google BigQuery : Inserting data into temporary table for joining it onto another table

Tags: java, sql, database, google-bigquery, temp-tables

I am currently trying to push some data from Java into BigQuery, in order to be able to make use of it only for the next query and then to get rid of it.
The data consists of 3 columns which exists in the table I want to query. Therefore, by creating a temporary table containing this data, I could make a left join and get the query results I am in need of.

This process will happen on a scheduled basis, having different sets of data.

Can you please tell me if that can be done ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`jobs.query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs) API, you can specify a `destinationTable` as part of `configuration.query`. Does that help? You can control the table expiration time using the [`tables.update`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables) API and setting `expirationTime`.

Alternatively, you can "inline" the table as part of the query that you want to run using a [`WITH` clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#with_clause) in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) rather than writing to a temporary table.